# Meaning of internal energy in the First Law of Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, energy-conservation

In my textbook, I have learnt that the First Law of Thermodynamics states
$$ΔU = Q - W$$
where $Q$ is the heat energy applied to the system, $W$ is the work done by the system on its surroundings, and $ΔU$ is the change in the total internal energy of the object.

I have learnt that $U$ includes all forms of energy, including translational/vibrational/rotational KE and PE. Additionally, temperature is determined only by translational KE.

However, excercises in my textbook make it out to seem that an increase in $U$ (whether via work or heat energy) always results in an increase in temperature as well. I do not understand how this can be if $U$ includes forms of energy not counted in temperature. How can work done on an object (e.g. accelerating it with a constant force over some distance in a vacuum) increase the random translational KE of its atoms?

An additional related question is the following: a rubber band holding 5J of elastic potential is released, converting the EPE to KE. My textbook states that in this case $W = -5J$ and this results in an increase of 5J in $U$. However, in my understanding $U$ includes both PE and KE, so if PE was converted into KE there should be no change in $U$.

What am I misinterpreting about the nature of $U$ and the relationship between temperature and $ΔU$?

Comment: "Additionally, temperature is determined only by translational KE." This is simply incorrect, which is the basis for at least part of your confusion. Where did you learn this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have learnt that $U$ includes all forms of energy, including
> translational/vibrational/rotational KE and PE.

Yes, but it is important to realize that the KE and PE components of the internal energy $U$ is the KE and PE associated with the motion and position of the molecules of the system, i.e., KE and PE at the microscopic level. The motion and positions you cannot observe directly. That is why they call it "internal" energy.

It is not the mechanical KE and PE of the system as a whole due to its velocity or position relative to an external frame of reference. I like to call this the "external" KE and PE of the system because they are associated with an external (to the system) frame of reference. These are the $\Delta KE$ and $\Delta PE$ in the general equation of the first law given in @Chet Miller answer.

> Additionally, temperature is determined only by translational KE.

This statement can be misleading. Although the kinetic temperature doesn't take into account vibrational and rotational forms of molecular kinetic energy, the specific heats do take them into account, and the specific heats determine the temperature change for a given amount of heat transfer in the absence of work.

> However, exercises in my textbook make it out to seem that an increase
> in $U$ (whether via work or heat energy) always results in an increase
> in temperature as well.

I'm not sure what those exercises are, but an increase in internal energy does not always result in an increase in temperature. For example, adding heat to cause a phase change from a solid to a liquid (e.g, melting of ice) increases internal energy with no change in temperature. That's because the heat addition only increases the internal PE, not KE of the water molecules. On the other hand, heating an ideal gas results in only an increase in translational KE.

> How can work done on an object (e.g. accelerating it with a constant
> force over some distance in a vacuum) increase the random
> translational KE of its atoms?

Acceleration of the system as a whole increases the KE of the system as a whole, its external mechanical KE. The general form of the first law, given to you in @Chet Miller answer, tell us that the total change in energy of the object is the sum of the change in its microscopic internal PE and KE, which constitutes $\Delta U$, plus the change in its macroscopic mechanical PE and KE, the $\Delta PE$ and $\Delta KE$ in the general equation of the first law, like the thrown ball example above.

> (Additional question). However, in my understanding $U$ includes both
> PE and KE, so if PE was converted into KE there should be no change in
> $U$.

If the conversion is between the internal (molecular) PE and internal (molecular) KE then yes, there should be no change in internal energy $U$. But it's not clear (at least to me) if they are treating the 5J of elastic potential energy as external mechanical PE of $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ (like a spring) or internal intermolecular potential energy.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are right to have doubts.  In general, U is a function of both temperature and specific volume.  But for some substances, like ideal gases and incompressible liquids, it is a function only of temperature.  But, for most other substances (e.g., real gases), constant U does not imply constant temperature.

When macroscopic kinetic- and potential energy are involved, one must use the more general form of the first law that includes these:
$$\Delta U+\Delta (KE)+\Delta(PE)=Q-W$$

Answer (score 0):

$ U$ is specifically the sum of all energies in a given system. Normally,
$$U=KE+PE$$
where, KE is kinetic energy, and PE is potential energy.

Now in thermodynamics, when we talk about ($\Delta U$,$W,Q$) they are likely concerned with gaseous state of matter. Normally, we often use $ideal\,\, gases$.
Ideal gases are gases which have all molecules spherical, and most importantly, they don't have molecular forces of attraction (or rather negligible). So, our $PE=0$, since we dont have any internal forces. Hence,

$$\Delta U=KE$$

Now using law of equipartition of energy (that kinetic energy in any direction is equal) and ideal gas equation ($PV=nRT$), we find out $V_{rms}$ of gas. We found,
$$KE=\frac{1}{2}mv_{rms}^2$$
where, $v_{rms}=\sqrt{\frac{3RT}{M}}$ and $m$ is mass of one molecule and $M$ is molar mass
So, we get:
$$KE=\frac{3}{2}nRT$$
OR
$$U=\frac{3}{2}nRT$$
OR
$$\Delta U=\frac{3}{2}nR\Delta T$$

Actually, this true only for monoatomic gases which dont have scope of rotational or vibrational motion. So we actually use $f$, degree of freedom, which counts for these motion. It can be though of as extension to equipartition law.
Hence, we can, write:
$$\Delta U=\frac{f}{2}nR\Delta T$$

Answer to your additional question:
If rubber band doesn't experience any external force, then change in total energy of system of rubber band ($\Delta U$) must be zero.